# Can frequency be mapped in stat_summary? If so, how?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot how much money on average was `awarded` to people from different departments (`dpt`). This I got using `stat_summary` (based on [this sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xs8xtadgwedsnhw/data.csv?dl=0)).

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(x, aes(dpt, awarded, color = dpt)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ type) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point")
```

[image]

This plot is faceted according to the `type` of job (`A` or `B`). However, I would like to add another variable, which is the number of jobs - each bubble's size should be proportional to the number of occurrences of that department in the data.

Is there a way to do it with some `ggplot2` command, or should it be computed beforehand and somehow implemented into the plot? If so, how exactly?

Alternatively, please suggest a better solution. Thanks! ;-)

Comment: I would probably summarize the data first, outside of `ggplot`, calculating the mean and number of cases, and then simply map them in `geom_point`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for example, something like this:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat_sum <- ddply(dat,
                 .(type,dpt),
                 summarise,
                 mean_awrd = mean(awarded,na.rm = TRUE),
                 n = length(dpt))

ggplot(dat_sum) + 
   facet_wrap(~type) + 
   geom_point(aes(x = dpt,y = mean_awrd,size = n,color = dpt))
```